# What was the Live action TV Show about Magicians?

Tags: story-identification

So I was thinking about this television show I saw a while back, pretty sure it was a TV Show anyway.  In this show it's based in I believe modern times, magic is real but most people don't know that it is.  There are real life magicians that are able to use magic but I believe they were rare.  In one of the scenes a stage magician was doing the floating card trick and somebody told him try doing it without using tricks, when he started to attempt it the card started to actually float.  He then found out that he was one of the real magicians.

Information pertaining to this show :

- The show should be around early new millenia probably between
  2000-2007, there's not other details I can remember.  Does anybody
  have any idea what show this is?
- I saw this show in USA

Comment: How long ago is "a while back"? Any recollections of names of actors/characters? Was it in English?

Comment: It was in English and should be early 2000's... possibly late 90's but I don't think it was.

Comment: What country did you see the program in?

Comment: I saw this in the USA

Comment: @FuzzyBoots A couple of possible candidates would be the forgotten TV movies [Now You See It](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0426568/) (Disney, 2005) and [The Magicians](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0243848/) (AKA Death by Magic, UPN, 2000). Both are about a young street\stage magician in modern times, discovering magic is real and (I think) some form of the floating card trick. Not sure enough to put up an answer, though.

Answer (score 5):

Since the question is from before the TV show aired this can't be correct.  Leaving the answer here in case someone else thinks it might be the answer.

Sounds like it could be The Magicians which was from 2009.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magicians_(American_TV_series)

In the first episode (or at least very near the start) one of the main characters is interviewing for a place at a prestigious school.  Card tricks are a hobby which he wants to demonstrate, but he is not a professional stage magician.  The interviewer wants him to do *real* magic.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wkKp.jpg]

Comment: The _novel_ was from 2009. The TV series aired from 2015-2020.

Comment: I think the OP is misremembering the dates -- the described scene is *exactly* the protagonist's Brakebill's admission interview.

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon - But the question was asked in May of 2014, a full 18 months before the _The Magicians_ TV series premiered in December 2015.

Comment: @LogicDictates your logic is impeccable.  I modified the answer to indicate it can't be correct and why to forestall anyone else who thinks the same thing.  Not sure whether the protocol is to delete wrong answers but that seemed best.

Comment: Lol at impeccable logic since I was thinking the same thing. The first book was published in 2009 so it's around the right time. It would be funny if OP read the book and got it confused with the Desden files show since that would mean 2 correct answers.

Answer (score 3):

Could it have been [the Dresden Files](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0486657/?ref_=nv_sr_1)?  The show was a short-lived TV series about a wizard living in modern Chicago, the only wizard to break the rules and go public with his (real) magic.

It was based on a series of books of the same name by Jim Butcher.

[image]

Comment: That's what I was thinking about earlier... I was trying to see if there was a flashback scene or something where he performed the card trick.

Comment: I don't think he ever did, but his dead dad was a stage magician and there were several flashbacks with him performing on stage.